# Is there a way to determine sensitive data in HTTP/HTTPS POST Body?

Tags: android, https, nlp, packet, text-extraction

I'm working on developing the system that can determine the chance of sensitive data leakage via HTTPS POST requests. To be honest, I'm really newbie in this field. Anyway, I realised that mostly the data like text will be sent as a key-value pairs. So, I tried to bring something like keyword matching to detect the key like username, password, or GPS Location. BUT it doesn't work well because the key do not have to be labeled correctly, like "username".

I stuck here. Is there anyway to determine what the type the value is?

ALSO, can I use text analysis with this kind of system? I want to inspect on HTTPS POST requests that I used Proxie (application) to export it as raw TCP text files.

Comment: Your computer program will need human-level intelligence to determine what data is sensitive. On the other hand, extracting data from HTTP posts is relatively simple. I recommend trying one problem at a time.

Comment: Post some sample requests along with example of data you want to flag. Is it just username, GPS, password data or other types of sensitive data to flag also?